# How to change current input keyboard programmatically

Tags: android

Android allows user to install their favourite keyboard and allow developers to create input keyboard. My question is if a user have multiple installed input keyboard, how to change current input keyboard to another installed input keyboard programmatically.

The definition of input keyboard is not the number or text or symbol input type on keyboard, but keyboard itself.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I do not understand... Do you have two plugged in keyboards?

Comment: sorry you can not force user to use custom keyboard. If custom keyboard is installed and user manually enable the custom keyboard then it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that is for security reasons not possible!